# How do I deploy local git repo from one account to another new git repo

Tags: git, html, javascript, css, react.js

I have a project setup locally which is on github. Now I have created a new git account with a fresh blank repo on git. I want my local project deploy on this newly created git account repo

Answer (score 0):

You just need to push your repo on new origin
Relate to this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7630574/git-push-everything-to-new-origin

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).